# Nested Table Layout Panels

Tags: vb.net, tablelayoutpanel

I am building an application that will show / hide portions of the form as the user completes it. I will use a TableLayoutPanel for ease of resizing (hide / show) all my controls.

My question is:

Is it more efficient to create a large TableLayoutPanel with all columns necessary for the controls that will be in the form, or should I nest a TableLayoutPanel into another?

On MSDN's [TableLayoutPanel page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171689%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), it tells us that it is better practice not to nest them due to debugging ... But debugging will not be a problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your requirements. Please show your layout for me to provide more detailed answer. In general, I would use TableLayoutPanel + nested [panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)s inside that. You can put multiple controls on a panel, so you should be able to accomplish what you need with it. Having nested TableLayoutPanel is not only a debugging concern, but also a UI designer's concern. I bet you will spend considerable time designing such a form and making sure it behaves as expected.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the input, I'll try panels inside TableLayouts